# Are there advantages to using earliest deadline first?

Tags: scheduling, freertos, rtos

In dynamic scheduling, you have primarily two options: [Earliest deadline first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) (EDF) or [least laxity first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_slack_time_scheduling) (LLF). LLF is preferable in a multiple-core architecture, because in it, it is possible that low-execution time jobs that have high laxity will prevent high-execution low-laxity time jobs from executing before their deadline.

But what advantages do we have using EDF? Is it the lower resource cost?